# @RepositoryRestResource did not work Spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE. while running occured error RegionRepository must only contain a single path segment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/region", collectionResourceRel = "list", excerptProjection = CustomRegion.class)
public interface RegionRepository extends JpaRepository<Region, Integer> {
}
```

**data rest class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProfUzApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfUzApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**main running class**

**Occured error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/saidk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks]: Factory method 'entityLinks' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Path /region configured for uz.pdp.prof.repository.RegionRepository must only contain a single path segment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to  mention path='endpoint name' without using '/' in @RepositoryRestResource. You have to use @RepositoryRestResource(path = **"region"**), it's direct spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints at **/region**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is happening because you defined the path using "/". Spring does not allow us to define a composed path like "/api/v1/my_entity". Just remove the "/" from your path and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project based on 2.2.2 a couple days ago and got the same issue.

After a few tries, the way to fix it is to use the same value in path and collectionResourceRel. In your case, try to use "region" in both path and collectionResourceRel.

Comment: One more question in your code is that JpaRepository<RegionRepository, Integer>, I think you are supposed to Region entity instead of RegionRepository.